# Maclaurin series of $\ln(2+x^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion

> Find the Maclaurin series of $\ln(2+x^2)$.

I know that $\displaystyle\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n} x^n $

So is $\displaystyle\ln(1+x^2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n} x^{2n}$?

I don't know what to do next then.

Comment: Yes indeed. You can replace $x$ by $x^2$. However notice that the domain of $x$ changes. For the first one $x\in(-1,\,\infty)$ and for the second $x\in [0,\,\infty)$ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking at $\ln 2+\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)$. Use the series for $\ln(1+t)$, and replace $t$ everywhere by $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$.